# Calling Oracle autonomous stored procedure from trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I have an Oracle trigger which is calling a stored procedure that has PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION defined.  The values that are passed from the trigger have been committed already but it appears that the values are not available in the stored procedure?  I'm not positive of this since the ability to debug/log/commit is difficult and the timing of the output is confusing me a bit.  I'd like to know if it's expected that any passed values are simply available in the stored procedure regardless of the AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values passed in to a stored procedure as parameters will always be available to the stored procedure.  It doesn't matter whether the procedure is declared using an autonomous transaction.

Code running in an autonomous transaction cannot see changes made by the calling transaction.  9 times out of 10, when people are describing problems seeing the data they expect, this is the source of the problem.

If your stored procedure is doing anything other than writing something to a log table, I would be exceptionally cautious about using autonomous transactions.  If you are using autonomous transactions for anything other than logging, you are almost certainly using them incorrectly.  And you are probably introducing a whole host of bugs related to race conditions and transactional integrity.

Comment: The trigger on table ABC calls the stored procedure which is doing a select on the same ABC table.  In this case, without the pragma I was receiving the "ORA-04091: table ABC is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" error from the stored procedure.  The only activity in the stored procedure other than SELECT statements is the logging that is done in the event of exceptions which does an INSERT/COMMIT.

Comment: @McArthey - Using autonomous transactions to work around a mutating trigger error is almost always a mistake.  Since the SELECT statement can't see the changes made by the triggering statement, that implies that your SELECT should either be done in a before statement trigger (because you don't care about the changes the current statement is making) or that you need a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, it's true that I don't care about the changes the trigger is making but we are watching for a specific change.  When a change occurs the stored procedure is called to do some analysis of the row values.  The stored procedure does not make any updates or inserts to the table in question.

Comment: @McArthey - But do you care about the changes the triggering statement is making?  I would assume that you do, otherwise having the trigger call the procedure would seem odd.  An autonomous transaction cannot by definition see the changes that the triggering statement is in the process of making.

Comment: It's a bit of a strange setup. The trigger is inserting/updating a secondary table (call it table B) which is monitoring table A via the trigger. The trigger logic is conditionally updating Table B which calls the stored procedure to select from the values on Table A so that Table B can be updated with a calculated value.  This is why I say that the stored procedure doesn't care what the values are in the table that is executing the trigger.

Comment: If I move the call to the stored procedure to an after insert for Table B, I believe I will still have the same problem because Trigger A is causing Trigger B to execute which is then calling the stored procedure.  Am I just moving the same issue to another trigger since it's all part of the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

> "The trigger logic is conditionally
>   updating Table B which calls the
>   stored procedure to select from the
>   values on Table A so that Table B can
>   be updated with a calculated value. "

Perhaps Table B really ought to be a Materialized View derived from Table A?  We can build a lot of complexity into the WHERE clauses of the queries which populate MViews. [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6002.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a row level trigger on table_x, then that trigger can be fired multiple times by the same statement as different rows are impacted by that statement.

The order in which those rows are impacted is indeterminate. As such, the state of table_x is indeterminate during the execution of a row level trigger. This is why the MUTATING TABLE exception is raised.

An autonomous transaction 'cheats' by looking at the committed state of the table (ie excluding all changes made by that statement, and other statements in the transaction).

If you want a stored procedure to look at the state of table_x in response to activity on that table, then it needs to be done after all the rows changes have been made (ie in a statement level trigger, not a row level trigger).

The design pattern for this is often to set a flag (package level variable) in a row level trigger, check the flag in an AFTER statement level trigger, and if necessary action it and reset it.

Comment: In my scenario I believe, then, that Table_A trigger would Insert to Table_B.  Table_B AFTER trigger would fire and execute the stored procedure which would SELECT from Table_A and update Table_B?  Wouldn't I have the same issue with the stored procedure since it is all part of the same transaction?